# How to remove identifierUris using PowerShell in Azure Active Directory Application

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am following this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/09/01/how-to-create-an-azure-ad-application-in-powershell/
to create `Azure Active Directory Application` using `PowerShell` but it fails because `identifierUris` already exists.

```
$appName = "yourappname123"
$uri = "http://yourappname123"
$secret = "yoursecret123"

$azureAdApplication = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName -HomePage $Uri -IdentifierUris $Uri -Password $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $secret -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Is it possible to delete identifier before creating application or a validation check whether identifierUri exists before creating application

Comment: @Theo. this is what i needed. thanks! and infact this is what i was looking for in my previous question

Comment: @Theo You could add your comment as an answer to help others, thanks.

Comment: As requested, I have added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Get-AzADApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azadapplication?view=azps-2.1.0) with parameter `-IdentifierUri` to test if there already is an app with that IdentifierUri:

```
$appName  = "yourappname123"
$uri      = "http://yourappname123"
$secret   = "yoursecret123"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $secret -AsPlainText -Force

# test if an app using that uri is already present
$app = (Get-AzADApplication -IdentifierUri $uri)
if ($app) {
    Write-Warning "An app with identifier uri '$uri' already exists: '$($app.DisplayName)'"
    # there already is an app that uses this identifier uri..
    # decide what to do:
    # - choose a new uri for the new app?
    # - change the identifier uri on the existing app?
    #   you can do that using 
    #   $app | Update-AzADApplication -IdentifierUri 'THE NEW URI FOR THIS APP'
}
else {
    # all seems clear; create your new app
    $azureAdApplication = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName -HomePage $Uri -IdentifierUris $Uri -Password $password
}
```